# GET data from database based on the tabPanel selection. RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I would like to retrieve the data based on the tab selection.For Eg., If I click on Tab A it should display tab a data and so on.
My code is working only when I commented out datatableoutput in 2 tabs. Else, it is displaying an empty page.

Below is the code I used.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(RODBC)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    x <- req(input$tabs)
    print(x)
    sql <- paste0("EXEC [dbo].[usp_GET_Applications] @pCategory_Name=N'", input$tabs,"'")
    res = connectionBtS$sqlQuery(sql)
    dfData <- res$getResult()
    dfData <- data.frame(dfData) 

    DT::datatable(dfData %>% select("Application","Description","Contact", "Email"), escape = FALSE ,
                  options = list(
                    columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(4), visible = FALSE)),
                    rowCallback = JS(
                    "function(row, data) {",
                    "var full_text =  data[4] ",
                    "$('td:eq(3)', row).attr('title', full_text);",
                    "}"))
                  )
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(h1(titlePanel("TITLE"))), 

  tabsetPanel(id="tabs",

    tabPanel("Tab A", value="A",DT::dataTableOutput("table")),

    tabPanel("Tab B", value="B", DT::dataTableOutput("table")),

    tabPanel("C", # value="C",DT::dataTableOutput("table")),

  )))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Looking forward for help. 
Many thanks.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate `id` such as `table`, you need to create new ones such as `table1`, `table2`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you cannot have objects with the same `id`, so try to render different objects

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1(titlePanel("TITLE")),

    tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                tabPanel("Tab A", 
                         value="A",
                         DT::dataTableOutput("table")
                ),
                tabPanel("Tab B", 
                         value="B", 
                         DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
                ),

                tabPanel("Tab C", 
                         value="C",
                         DT::dataTableOutput("table3")
                )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    table_data <- reactive({
        head(mtcars)
    })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        table_data()
    })

    output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        table_data()
    })

    output$table3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        table_data()
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```